# Split Numpy array using Index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, graph

I have 3D array as

```
pcar=[[xa ya za]
      [xb yb zb]
      .
      .
      [xn yn zn]]
```

and index array as

```
[0,1,0....,2]
```

which gives rows in `pcar` should go in which cluster so that I can plot it in different color. The maximum value of clusters is 3.

Output should be

```
clusters[0] = [[xa ya za], [xc yc zc], ...]
clusters[1] = [[xb yb zb], ...]
clusters[2] = [..., [xn yn zn]]
```

and I want to print that points in graph with each cluster points having different color

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: what output do you expect? something like `[xa, yb, xc, ... zn]`?

Comment: @njzk2 I have edited my question to show output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to generate a list of clusters like the following:

```
clusters[0] = [[xa ya za], [xc yc zc], ...]
clusters[1] = [[xb yb zb], ...]
clusters[2] = [..., [xn yn zn]]
```

This is quite easy to do with NumPy indexing. Let the index array be called `indices`. Then,

```
indices = np.asarray(indices)
num_clusters = 3
clusters = [pcar[indices==i] for i in xrange(num_clusters)]
```

will give you the desired result.

Comment: `indices==i` is a boolean, you can't use that as an index. you probably need to find the indices of `i` in `indices`, if your interpretation of the question is correct.

Comment: @njzk2: `indices==i` is a boolean NumPy array, so it can be used for indexing.

Comment: @DummyGuy: OK, I was adding the `asarray` for insurance. You are free to remove it.

Comment: @nneonneo Can u tell me how would I print clustering points in 3D graph with different color?. I have did it for same color before split.

Comment: @DummyGuy: No, sorry, I don't know.

Comment: @nneonneo : ok, didn't know about that boolean numpy array. pretty neat !

Comment: does something like `[x for index,x in enumerate(pcar) if indices[index] == i]`, then?

Comment: @njzk2: Yes, that's roughly correct, but it's much faster than doing it in pure Python.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
indices = [0,1,0....,2]
[pcar[i][index] for i, index in enumerate(indices)]
# [xa, yb, xc, ... zn]
```